# ngRoute: 404 not found after Grunt build

Tags: angularjs, nginx, gruntjs, ngroute

I have an `AngularJS` project which has two views; `/settings` and `/`. The `app.js` file looks like;

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
      templateUrl: './views/bill.html',
      controller: 'BillCtrl'
  })

  .when('/settings', {
    templateUrl: './views/settings.html',
    controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
  })

  .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Where all the routes are defined.

Then I have `app/views/bill.html` & `app/views/settings.html`.

Now, `grunt serve` works perfectly where I can go to any view using `ngHref`. The problem is when I do `grunt build` and have `nginx` pointed to the build directory (the path is `/kds`), I see a `GET http://localhost/views/settings.html 404 (Not Found)`

The path should be relative, and hence, it should be a `GET http://localhost/kds/views/settings.html` but that's not the case. What's going on here?

This looks more like a bad server configuration than anything else. Or is the build messing things up for me?

The server directive is;

`location /kds {
    alias /Users/asheshambasta/code/kds/dist/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}`

**EDIT** (full `app.js`)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('kdsApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'apiService',
  'Lib',
  'ngTouch',
  'ipCookie'
  ])

.run(['$location', 'ipCookie', 'APICfg', function($location, ipCookie, APICfg) {
    var login = ipCookie('lgInf');
    if (!login || !login.usr || !login.pass || !login.srv) {
        $location.path('/settings');
    } else {
        APICfg.setSrv(login.srv);
        APICfg.setCId(login.cId);
    }
}])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/views/bill.html',
      controller: 'BillCtrl'
  })

  .when('/settings', {
    templateUrl: '/views/settings.html',
    controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
  })

  .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

All the files needed by the application:

```
  <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/apiservice.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/lib.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/class/bill.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/class/item.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/class/course.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/bill.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/controllers/settings.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the website under a subfolder of you host.

Example:

```
http://localhost/kds
```

So when you make ng-route work with html5 it will understand that you need to move to '/' because there is no '/kds' defined.

1 trick that you can do is use `<base href="/kds">`

put this in your `<head>`

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/kds">
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

This will make all your routes or templatesUrls be prefixed with this base.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work for me. Now it begins to look for everything in the root `/` path and the application fails.
I also to a `$location.path('/settings')` in my `app.run` if the username/pass is not found, but that isn't the problem.

Comment: I am a litle confused about how you have your source files. My sugestion is for when you have all your source in a subpath of you host inviroment. Example all in the path /kds.

Comment: Please add the full path of all files required by the aplication. Ex: app.js is on http://localhost/app.js, settings.html is on http://localhost/views/settings.html and so on. i think your problem is about that configuration.

Comment: I've added all the files I include in index.html

Comment: Your problem is not with the javascript files. it is because of the path angular needs to calculate. when you tell templateUrl: '/views/bill.html' you are telling angular to find the view in `localhost/views/bill.html` open chrome debug tools and check the nagivation tab and see what the link angular is trying to find. them try remove the '/' from templateUrl.

Comment: I'm afraid removing the `/` from `templateUrl` doesn't work for me either. The link the app is trying to find is not relative, it tries to find `/views` in the root of the server and not relative to where the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed in the end was setting up the base href dynamically. Also, the `base href` has a few gotchas: the relative path should have trailing and leading `\`; and using javascript you can set it as:

```
  <script>
    document.write("<base href='" + document.location.pathname + "' />");
  </script>
```